# Global variable is undefined inside a const function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When I try to get current value of a variable outside a const function in React then it would not an issue, while getting access to a variable INSIDE a const function it gives me an error.

```js
const revealMatchedWord = (string, guessed) => {
    if(string.length > 0) {
        const regExpr = new RegExp(`[^${guessed.join("")}\\s]`, 'ig');
        return string.replace(regExpr, '_');
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

let curr = revealMatchedWord(guessWord, updatedArray);
let isGuessed = curr === guessWord; // check if word is guessed
console.log('isGuessed ' + isGuessed); // true

const checkLetters = () => {
    console.log('isGuessed ' + isGuessed); // undefined
}

    const handleKeyPress = useCallback(event => {
        let letter = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
        if(event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
            checkLetters();
        } else if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
        }
    }, [handleKeyPress]);

return (
  <div>
        <p>{revealMatchedWord(guessWord, updatedArray)}</p>
  </div>
)
```

In vanilla this.isGuessed should be working properly but in React this is not the case.

Comment: Whether or not `this.isGuessed` works really depends on where the code is evaluated/executed. E.g. this will only work in global scope, but when you write React I assume you are using modules. This doesn't work in modules (no matter whether you use React or not). There is also no reason to use `this`. Just reference the variable directly.

Comment: Yes, but even isGuessed is not working inside the function

Comment: Where/how are you calling checkLetters?

Comment: it doesn't look like you're putting isGuessed on this at all. Try using it without this and just isGuessed inside the function

Comment: Change from fat arrow () => {} to function() {} in your checkLetters function.

Comment: Sidenote: I assume this is inside a React component, so `isChecked` isn't actually global. If just referring to `isGuessed` gives you `undefined` then 1) `isGuessed` doesn't have the correct value assigned 2) you are not using hooks correctly and somehow you are calling an "old" version of the function.

Comment: Please update the example and make it actually runnable. Stack snippets allow you to use React and JSX. Nothing prevents you from creating a self contained example.

Comment: try making `isGuessed` as state using `useState` hook in the react component and try to access the value after that through the hook

Answer (score 1):

It's because of yout `useCallback` you need to pass a second parameter for the "cache" version to update.

```
    const handleKeyPress = useCallback(event => {
        // logic here
    }, [isGuessed]);
```

Pass the is guessed so `handleKeyPress` will re update the resulting value if `isGuessed` change.

Comment: I found the proper answer

Comment: @Daniel which is exactly this answer lol. (Look at the answer he posted here)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    useEffect(() => {
       checkLetters(isGuessed);
    }, [isGuessed]);
```